# How do you call this? bash[146155] in /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, syslog

Content in /var/log/messages

```
Jan 17 15:32:34 SERVER1 bash[146155]: user1 as root: ls -l
Jan 17 15:32:34 SERVER1 bash[146155]: user1 as root: cd
```

user1=who am i

root=whoami

ls -l and cd = $BASH_COMMANDS

SERVER1 = echo $HOST

bash[146155] =????

My output in my script:

Jan 17 15:32:34 SERVER1: user1 as root: ls -l

bash[id] is missing.

content of my script:

1. if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
2. trap "caller >/dev/null || \
3. printf '%s\n' \"\$(date '+%b %d %T')\
4. \$(hostname -s) \$(logname) as \$(whoami): \${BASH_COMMAND}\" 2>/dev/null >>/var/log/messages" DEBUG
5. fi

Comment: My script..  if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
    trap "caller >/dev/null || \
printf '%s\\n' \"\$(date '+%b %d %T')\
 \$(hostname -s) \$(logname) as \$(whoami): \${BASH_COMMAND}\" 2>/dev/null >>/var/log/messages" DEBUG
fi

Comment: I am not sure I get your problem, despite its content, /var/log/messages is intended to be read by human, you can add any content.

Answer (score 2):

The `bash[146155]` in the logfile is the name of the process that sent the message to the log (in this case the `bash` shell) followed by the process ID (PID) of this process in square brackets.

The PID is included in the logfile so that an individual process may be identified. If a program misbehaves in some way, it may otherwise be hard to track what *instance* of the program it is that is acting up.  This is particularly true for programs such as `bash`, `java`, `sshd` etc. that usually are executing in multiple processes on a system.

Comment: mere indication of programm name is not enough (there can be many "bash" or "java"), that's why pid is given in bracket.

Comment: @Archemar Yes. I will add this.

Comment: My question is every command that i type it gives me this bash[146155].. How can i reproduce that? other fields there is i can reproduce. But the bash with id?

Comment: You are the user who asked [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338073/log-all-the-command-by-user).  You have your logging solution turned on maybe?

Comment: Yes, I recreate the histlog.sh in /etc/profile.d , but what i am missing is the bash id.

Comment: @invinzin21 I don't understand. Please update the question with the relevant info, or this question will _also_ be closed for being unclear.

Comment: i apologize.. Yes I am the one who ask question. You help me with unset PROMPT_COMMAND.

Comment: my question is,, how can i reproduce it?